# Port number to name

Tags: php, networking, port

In order to make statistics. I want to get port name.

Is there an API or a class to get port name from port number ?

> Example : 443 -> https

Thank you for help :)

Comment: keep in mind that the portnumber can be different set by admins ;)

Comment: unix: `/etc/services`. windoze: `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\services`. both are simple text files, doing `portname  portnum/protocol # description` for format

Comment: i tried http://www.frameip.com/liste-des-ports-tcp-udp/ but there is no API

Comment: @donald123 : i agree 
Thank you for all